# How to draw line between two labels on tkinter Canvas using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to draw a line between two labels on a canvas, but I do not know how to get the label coordinates to do this - I need to generate a large and variable number of labels each time, which I position on the canvas using pack() or grid.

An example of my code is as below:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

def line(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    w.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)

label1 = tk.Label(master, text="ONE", bg="red", fg="white")
label1.pack(side="left")
label2 = tk.Label(master, text="TWO", bg="blue", fg="white")
label2.pack(side="right")

w = tk.Canvas(master, width=800, height=100)
w.pack()

line(label1.winfo_rootx(), label1.winfo_rooty(), 
     label2.winfo_rootx(), label2.winfo_rooty())

master.mainloop()
```

The above code does not generate any line, but it does display the labels. How can I get the correct coordinates for these labels so I can then use them in the line method to actually draw a line connecting the two labels?

Comment: The two labels should not be inside the canvas.  You should use `w.create_window(...)` to put the labels inside the canvas.  Then you can use `w.bbox(...)` to get the bounding boxes of the labels and draw line to connect them.

Answer (score 1):

I found I can do what I need done (i.e. draw connecting lines between labels generated on the canvas) by using place geometry instead of pack. For a large number of automatically generated labels, this means using a small method to generate the placement coordinates, but once those sets of coordinates are generated, then joining the labels is easy.

For example:

```
label1 = tk.Label(master, text="ONE", bg="red", fg="white")
label1.place(x=50, y=80)
label2 = tk.Label(master, text="TWO", bg="blue", fg="white")
label2.place(x=720, y=80)
line(50, 80, 720, 80)
```

Another way to do this is to generate canvas text objects instead of labels. So this would be like follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

def line(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    print(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    w.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="green")


w = tk.Canvas(master, width=800, height=100)
w.pack()

l1 = w.create_text(50, 20, text="ONE", fill="red", tag="l1")
l2 = w.create_text(720, 20, text="TWO", fill="blue", tag="l2")
x1 = w.coords(l1)[0] + 20
y1 = w.coords(l1)[1]
x2 = w.coords(l2)[0] - 20
y2 = w.coords(l2)[1]
line(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```